# No redirect migration links broken for answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

The no-redirect links to the original site are broken for answers.  For example, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9138/revisions) history links to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts/306973#306973?noredirect=1
```

It should be:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts/306973?noredirect=1#306973
```

The noredirect=1 needs to be added to the query string.

Comment: Yes. The [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is supposed to be at the end of the URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next build.

I think the code responsible for rendering those links dates back to when we didn't record migration history events on answers and was never updated.